# Laravel Upload Image and Resize to Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: laravel, resize, spaces, digital, ocean

I try upload image and resize to digital ocean spaces, but the resize image code doesn't resize

```
 $image = $request->file('image');

    /**
     * save resize image
     */

    $thumb_uploads = env('CLOUD_POSTS_IMAGE_THUMB');

    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());

    $image_resize->resize(50, 50, function ($constraint) {

        $constraint->aspectRatio();

    })->save(Storage::disk('spaces')->put($thumb_uploads .'/'.$image->hashName(), file_get_contents($image), 'public'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you should use the resized images content.

```
$image_resize = $image_resize->resize(50, 50, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
})->encode('jpg');

Storage::disk('spaces')->put($thumb_uploads .'/'.$image->hashName(), (string) $image_resize);
```

Comment: thanks sir, image has been uploaded but image can't open

Comment: Make sure that the visibility of the image is `public` while putting it to the disk.

Comment: im try add to public, and still same

```
Storage::disk('spaces')->put($thumb_uploads .'/'.$image->hashName(), $image_resize->__toString(), 'public');
```

im try dd($image_resize->__toString()) this output empty

Comment: How exactly are you trying to get the image?

Comment: im check on the spaces digital ocean

Comment: how to check encode dynamic from image uploaded sir ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried above the code. But not running.

{
$imgpath200 = 'mechanic/category/200/'.$imgname;
$resizeImg200 = Image::make($realImg->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200, function($constraint) {
$constraint->aspectRatio();
// $constraint->upsize();
})->encode('png');
\Log::info('resize image');
\Log::info((string)$resizeImg200);
$result = $client->putObject([
'Bucket' => config('filesystems.disks.do_spaces.bucket'),
'Key' => $imgpath200,
'SourceFile' => $resizeImg200->stream()->__toString(),
'ACL' => 'public-read',
// 'ContentLength' => $fileSize,
])
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35452991)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).